# PHP MVC - Inclusão de CSS, Imagens etc

Tags: php, css, mvc, twig

Olá, na minha aplicação eu estou tendo problemas quando vou adicionar um arquivo css, imagem ou qualquer outro arquivo que seja frontend, pois quando irei incluir preciso setar todo o diretório do mesmo, por exemplo.

O diretório das views tem a seguinte estrutura

> - App/Controller/
> - App/Model/
> - App/View/Templates/Template_name (Ex: default)
> - Index.php

Só que quando vou incluir por exemplo o css, tenho que setar todo o diretório dos templates, tipo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu quero é, poder incluir sem precisar apontar todo o diretório.
Tipo, a partir de /templates/default/...

Comment: Seja mais específico sobre qual o problema, pois está muito vago.

Comment: Tinha esquecido de concluir após adicionar a imagem, perdoe-me. rs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### mod_rewrite / .htaccess

Habilite/instale o `mod_rewrite` no seu *servidor apache*.

### Configure seu .htaccess

Siga o modelo abaixo:

*(fiz a configuração apenas para o css, mas é possível customizar isso de 'n' maneiras)*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /app/view/templates/default/frontend/css/$1 [NC,L]
```

### O que você deve modificar no HTML?

Somente isso:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

E pronto!

O `.htaccess` irá efetuar o *redirecionamento interno* da url `/css/styles.css` para o destino correto (explicando de uma maneira mais simples).

---

Espero ter ajudado.

Qualquer dúvida deixa um comentário abaixo.

Comment: Funcionou como esperado?

Comment: Acho que você entendeu, pela lógica é isso aí mesmo, porém eu fiz uma alteração aqui e não funcionou.

RewriteRule ^templates/(.+)$ /app/view/templates/ [NC,L]

Ele dá erro, como se não tivesse encontrado o diretório.

Comment: O diretório que você mencionou acima é diferente. Deveria ser no caso: `/app/view/templates/default/frontend/css/$1 [NC,L]`. A rota que você mencionou acima está incorreta e faltando o parâmetro **$1** no final.

Comment: RewriteRule ^templates/(.+)$ /app/view/templates/$1 [NC,L]. 
Assim continua ocorrento o erro, o que eu queria é poder adicionar a partir do templates, por exemplo. /templates/default/.. Entendeu? rs, não posso inserir o default no htaccess pois é um sistema de skins. ^^

Comment: Neste caso já nao tem relação com o redirecionamento ou .htaccess, o que sua aplicação deve fazer é retornar o skin escolhido pelo usuário por exemplo, na sessão ou como uma configuração (arquivo/database) do usuário, e então concatenar com essa URL. Tipo assim: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/template/<?php echo $configuracao['skin'] ?>/frontend/css/estilos.css">` (é um exemplo apenas)

Comment: Sim sim, consegui dar um jeito aqui. rs
Mas em relação a gerir os templates estou vendo ainda, se salvo na database ou outra coisa. rs

Comment: Achei muito interessante sua resposta não sabia que dava para fazer isso também com os caminhos dos assets.

Você teria como me explicar melhor sobre o objeto desse linha para esse contexto que foi aplicado? 

    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

Answer (score 1):

Nós temos aqui na empresa uma aplicação no modelo MVC.
O que nós fizemos foi criar um ficheiro php com todas as definições e uma delas é a pasta com os estilos.

```
<?php
define("CSS_DIR","/app/view/templates/default/frontend/css/");
//outras definições
?>
```

Fazemos o include do ficheiro acima na index, antes de fazer a chamada ao css.
Depois fazemos referência a constante que criamos da seguinte forma:

```
<link href="<?=CSS_DIR.'nome_do_css.css';?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

É possível fazer com htaccess também, sabes trabalhar com htaccess?

Comment: Acho que não entendeu muito bem o meu objetivo. rs
isso aí seria apenas um define, mas no código de conte continuaria mostrando o diretório /app/view/.
Queria fazer como se a pasta de templates estivesse na raiz do sistema, entende?

Comment: Entendi, terá que ser feito com htaccess, mas qual o objectivo?

Comment: Quase isso aí que o Patrick postou acima. rs

Comment: Quase? Mas foi marcado como resposta certa, resolveu o problema?

Comment: Sim, depois de uns testes aqui funcionou. :)
O problema era na hora que eu trato o controler. rs

Answer (score 1):

Em minhas aplicações eu simplesmente crio uma pasta de arquivos públicos, separada do resto da estrutura, e crio pastas para cada projeto. Algo semelhante a isso:

- public

  - css

    - projeto 1
    - projeto 2
    - projeto n
  - img

    - projeto 1
    - projeto 2
    - projeto n
  - js

    - projeto 1
    - projeto 2
    - projeto n
- src
- vendor

A partir disso, simplesmente referencio os arquivos diretamente, usando uma barra como prefixo para evitar problemas com o url-rewrite caso o mod_rewrite do apache esteja habilitado (ou qualquer outro equivalente)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/projeto1/estilo.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/projeto1/arquivo.js"></script>
<img src="/img/projeto1/icone.gif" alt="icone" />
```

Caso seja necessário fazer com o que o twig possa abrir esses arquivos, basta criar um mapeamento para a pasta pública que você deseja.
Isso torna tudo muito mais simples.

Answer (score 0):

Exactamente para o que voçê quer, o mod_rewrite resolve a questão tal como o Patrick respondeu, mas elaborando um pouco mais, o .htaccess pode não ser considerada a opção mais "elegante", e nem todos os php web servers trabalham da mesma forma, voçê pode por exemplo usar outras alternativas como, um **symbolic link**, tanto o Windows como o Linux o suportam, mesmo que não tenhas acesso directo ao servidor, ie, se for partilhado, dá para fazer com um script PHP, ou então uma opção full PHP, como faço na minha framework que podes adaptar para a tua.

http://pedrosimoes79.github.io/silverbullet/

Na minha framework HMVC, o que faço é ter na view a path da view, que me permite definir paths de forma genérica assim:

view /examples/helloworld/views/hello.php

```
<script src="<?= $view_path ?>js/hello.js">
```

Aplicação/Módulo: helloworld
View: hello

E o path vai ser:

```
<script src="examples/helloworld/views/js/hello.js"></script>
```

Embora não seja exactamente a sua necessidade, para retirar o 'examples/helloworld/views/' pode-se como disse anteriormente criar um symbolic link, ou então a directoria css ou js poderia ser, sem problema algum definida na mesma path que o index.php.

Assim é permitido que cada triad MVC encapsule os seus recursos específicos.

http://pedrosimoes79.github.io/silverbullet/

Answer (score -2):

Um dos principais motivos é que está usando o link para o arquivo fixo, e deve ser dinâmico, por exemplo no modo fixo seria: pasta/subpasta/.../arquivo_css.css, mas no modo dinâmico , fica como http://seudominio.com.br/pasta/subpasta/.../arquivo_css.css, ou para uma foto http://seudominio.com.br/pasta/subpasta/.../foto.png. Assim ficando disponível para todos os arquivos, pois como disse se trata de um estrutura de rotas, com MVC. Abraço